# Postgresql update multiple rows and skip row on error

Tags: postgresql, update

I have a query which updates single column of multiple records using column value from another table. For example below are the tables--

Table A

```
+-----------------+---------------------+------+
| id(primary_key) | user_id(unique_key) | f_id |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+
| 1               | 1                   | 11   |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+
| 2               | 3                   | 22   |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+
```

Table B

```
+----+------+
| id | f_id |
+----+------+
| 1  | 11   |
+----+------+
| 3  | 22   |
+----+------+
```

Now I tried to update `user_id` column for all records in `Table A` using `id` column from `Table B` on basis of `f_id` column which is common using below query.

```
UPDATE 
    A
SET 
    user_id = B.id
FROM 
    B
WHERE A.f_id = B.f_id
```

`user_id` column in `Table A` is unique which generates an error on bulk update as:

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "A_user_id_key"
>   DETAIL: Key (user_id)=(221207) already exists.

But when I update this particular record using below query

```
UPDATE 
    A
SET 
    user_id = 221207
FROM 
    B
WHERE A.f_id = B.f_id
```

it executes successfully without any error. Only bulk updates shows that error.
I don't get what is going wrong.

Comment: Please add table schema of tables A and B.

Comment: I have created a minimal question to reproduce the error whole table has many columns but problem is when updating `user_id` column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is a UNIQUE INDEX on table A(user_id) and you're trying to assign an existing value to more than one row.

Have a look at the next example:

```
create table a (id int, user_id int, f_id int);
create table b (id int, f_id int);
create unique index A_user_id_key on a(user_id);

insert into a 
values (1, 1, 11),
       (2, 3, 22),
       (3, 2, 33),
       (4, 5, 44 );

insert into b
values (1, 11),
       (3, 22),
       (3, 33), --<<<< there is another row with user_id = 3
       (4, 44);
```

When I try to update using your current query:

```
update a
set    user_id = b.id
from   b
where  a.f_id = b.f_id;
```

It returns same error message:

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "a_user_id_key"
>   DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(3) already exists.

You could solve by avoiding existing values:

```
update a
set    user_id = b.id
from   b
where  a.f_id = b.f_id
and    not exists(select 1 from a where a.user_id = b.id);
```

This is the result:

> ```
> select * from a;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | user_id | f_id
> -: | ------: | ---:
>  1 |       1 |   11
>  2 |       3 |   22
>  3 |       2 |   33
>  4 |       4 |   44
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0d7c6bb5d3aaba3801144843f51194f7)*

But I'll suggest to check wich are the duplicate rows using next query:

> ```
> select a.*
> from   a
> join   b
> on     a.f_id = b.f_id
> and    exists(select 1 from a where user_id = b.id and f_id <> b.f_id);
> ```
>
> ```
> id | user_id | f_id
> -: | ------: | ---:
>  3 |       2 |   33
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=50e45403dcef4ce5bb02472236ae75fb)*

Comment: Thanks for your effort I will compare this with my original schema.